# Wish-list add to card getting "Please specify product's required option(s) for"

Tags: magento2, addtocart, wishlist

In wishlist items add to card click to getting error "Please specify product's required option(s) for"

Can you please let me how to custom option auto default select when add to card before 
I have found this file

> ```
> vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Model/ItemCarrier.php
> ```

```
public function moveAllToCart(Wishlist $wishlist, $qtys)
    {
        $isOwner = $wishlist->isOwner($this->customerSession->getCustomerId());

        $messages = [];
        $addedProducts = [];
        $notSalable = [];

        $cart = $this->cart;
        $collection = $wishlist->getItemCollection()->setVisibilityFilter();

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            /** @var $item \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item */
            try {
                $disableAddToCart = $item->getProduct()->getDisableAddToCart();
                $item->unsProduct();

                $options =  $item->getProduct()->getProductOptionsCollection();


                foreach ($options as $option) {
              //  print_r($option->getData()); 
                $values = $option->getValues();
                //loop all child options
                foreach($values as $value) {
                    if($value->getIsDefault()== 1){
                       $optionids= [$value->getData('option_id')=>$value->getData('option_type_id')];
                     // $item->setOptions($optionids); 
                    }

                }

             }

             //$cart->addProduct($optionids)->save();


               //$item->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($optionids));

                // Set qty
                if (isset($qtys[$item->getId()])) {
                    $qty = $this->quantityProcessor->process($qtys[$item->getId()]);
                    if ($qty) {
                        $item->setQty($qty);
                    }
                }
                $item->getProduct()->setDisableAddToCart($disableAddToCart);
                // Add to cart

                if ($item->addToCart($cart, $isOwner)) {
                    $addedProducts[] = $item->getProduct();
                }
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                if ($e instanceof ProductException) {
                    $notSalable[] = $item;
                } else {
                    $messages[] = __('%1 for "%2".', trim($e->getMessage(), '.'), $item->getProduct()->getName());
                }

                $cartItem = $cart->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($item->getProduct());
                if ($cartItem) {
                    $cart->getQuote()->deleteItem($cartItem);
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e);
                $messages[] = __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.');
            }
        }

        if ($isOwner) {
            $indexUrl = $this->helper->getListUrl($wishlist->getId());
        } else {
            $indexUrl = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('wishlist/shared', ['code' => $wishlist->getSharingCode()]);
        }
        if ($this->cartHelper->getShouldRedirectToCart()) {
            $redirectUrl = $this->cartHelper->getCartUrl();
        } elseif ($this->redirector->getRefererUrl()) {
            $redirectUrl = $this->redirector->getRefererUrl();
        } else {
            $redirectUrl = $indexUrl;
        }

        if ($notSalable) {
            $products = [];
            foreach ($notSalable as $item) {
                $products[] = '"' . $item->getProduct()->getName() . '"';
            }
            $messages[] = __(
                'We couldn\'t add the following product(s) to the shopping cart: %1.',
                join(', ', $products)
            );
        }

        if ($messages) {
            foreach ($messages as $message) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($message);
            }
            $redirectUrl = $indexUrl;
        }

        if ($addedProducts) {
            // save wishlist model for setting date of last update
            try {
                $wishlist->save();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t update the Wish List right now.'));
                $redirectUrl = $indexUrl;
            }

            $products = [];
            foreach ($addedProducts as $product) {
                /** @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */
                $products[] = '"' . $product->getName() . '"';
            }

            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __('%1 product(s) have been added to shopping cart: %2.', count($addedProducts), join(', ', $products))
            );

            // save cart and collect totals
            $cart->save()->getQuote()->collectTotals();
        }
        $this->helper->calculate();
        return $redirectUrl;
    }
```

Please let me know how to set custom default option select

Comment: Can you please let me know how to wishlist item add default option